# How to find all Django default form validation messages?

Tags: django, django-forms

Where can I find all the default validation error messages that Django outputs (ex. the field required error message)?

I want to translate these to another language and I know how to replace them but not how to find all of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `form` error messages you can browse through the `django.forms.fields` file and look for `default_error_messages`.

https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/forms/fields.py